# iOS game integrated with Facebook - Random game

Tags: iphone, ios, multiplayer, objective-c, facebook

How could I implement a [random game](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=the%20random%20game) for iOS via Facebook.  I registered my game with Facebook and done everything so far... Can Facebook do such a thing?

**EDIT**

I connected my app to Facebook, I can send requests, publish open graphs etc. But i need to connect players to play online via Facebook, such as [Bubble Galaxy with Buddies](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bubble-galaxy-with-buddies/id550308187?mt=8). Do they use Facebook for this? Any tutorial or idea ?

Comment: A quick google search turned up this [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/) for developing a simple facebook integrated ios app, so it is apparently possible.

Comment: i have done everything from that tutorial

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your question is really vague.

Comment: i will edit my question

Comment: i edited my question @bummzack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last time I used the Facebook API they didn't provide any multiplayer or gameplay functionality. I'm pretty sure you have to write that yourself.

You can still leverage the Facebook API to publish scores/achievements and find friends of a user. Eg. You can get the user-names, profile pictures from FB and also use the Facebook API to post something on the users wall to draw more attention to your game. [Achievements](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/achievements/) and [scores](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/scores/) are also a part of the Facebook API now.

The [tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-games/) you followed is pretty much all there is to it. Facebook gives you the "social" data of users, everything else is up to you.

To find friends for a multi-player game (as your question suggests), you could use the FB API to find the friends of a user which are currently online and send a request. Your server-application will have to handle the creation of a multi-player session when requests are being accepted.

Comment: Wonderful answer